# (deferLoad) event - How to know the visible items

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I'm using (deferLoad) to upload an image gallery in a "controlled" way. Is there an event that allows me to know which items are visible?

The objective is to load a set of information plus an image path and when the state of the visible item is true I use the url to load the image.

Is there a way to know which products are visible in order to get the image to an api, through an event or otherwise?

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejwlnp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**.TS**

```
<ul class="mdc-image-list my-image-list first">
    <li class="mdc-image-list__item" style="height:200px" *ngFor="let image of Images; let i = index"
        (deferLoad)="image.show = true">
        <ng-container *ngIf="image.show">
            <img [src]="image.url" style="height: 100%;width: 100%;">
            <div class="mdc-image-list-supporting"
                style="display: flex; align-items: center;flex-direction: column;padding: 2px">
                <span class="mdcImageListLabel">{{image.name}}</span>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) API. In Angular you can write a directive for handle that:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[lazySrc]'
})
export class ImgDataDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input('lazySrc') src: string;

  constructor(
    private _elRef: ElementRef,
    private _renderer: Renderer2,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
  ) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this._loadImage();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._renderer.setAttribute(this._elRef.nativeElement, 'src', PLACEHOLDER);

    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      const obs = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
        entries.forEach(({ isIntersecting }) => {
          if (isIntersecting) {
            this._loadImage();
            obs.unobserve(this._elRef.nativeElement);
          }
        });
      });
      obs.observe(this._elRef.nativeElement);
    }
  }

  private _loadImage() {
    this._renderer.setAttribute(this._elRef.nativeElement, 'src', this.src);
  }
}
```

Comment: Notice: for IE you should use a polyfill.

Comment: Does the idea of ​​the _loadImage () function serve to fetch the item's image from the API, with src being base64? How is the html part?
Thank you for your help

Comment: You can do inside of `_loadImage` anything you want, you can make an API call and set to src whatever you want. But in this case, don't forget to detect changes with `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck();`

Answer (score 0):

Your objective is to load the images visible on the screen.
You can achieve this by adding an attribute to image tag.

```
<img loading=lazy>
```

Source:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-loading
- https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/

Working Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agkfuq?file=src/app/app.component.html